# Regular expression explanation for vim

Tags: regex, vim

If I want all the lines with the text 'ruby' but not 'myruby' then this is what I would do.

```
:g/\<ruby\>/
```

My question is what is the meaning of lesser than and greater than symbol here? The only regular expression I have used is while programming in ruby.

Similarly if I want to find three consecutive blank lines then this is what I would do

```
/^\n\{3}
```

My question is why I am escaping the first curly brace ( opening curly brace ) but not escaping the second curly brace ( closing curly brace )?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the `\<` and `\>` mean word boundaries.  In Perl, grep and less (to name 3 OTOH) you use `\b` for this, so I imagine it's the same in Ruby.

Regarding your 2nd question, the escape is needed for the whole expression `{3}`.  You're not escaping each curly brace, but rather the whole thing together.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458915/searching-word-in-vim) for more.

Answer (score 15):

Vim's rules for backslash-escaping in regexes are not consistent.  You have to escape the opening brace of`\{...}`, but `[...]` requires no escaping at all, and a capture group is `\(...\)` (escaping both open and close paren).  There are other inconsistencies as well.

Thankfully Vim lets you change this behavior, even on a regex-by-regex basis, via the `magic` settings.  If you put `\v` at the beginning of a regex, the escaping rules become more consistent; everything is "magic" except numbers, letters, and underscores, so you don't need backslashes unless you want to insert a literal character other than those.

Your first example then becomes `:g/\v<ruby>/` and your second example becomes `/\v^\n{3}`.  See `:h /magic` and `:h /\v` for more information.

Comment: You can 'set magic' n your vimrc to always have magic mode.

By the way I think that a 'magic' expression is beginned by \m and not by \v

\v means 'no magic'

Comment: No, actually \v means "very magic". Which means that all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning so they don't have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

For your first regular expression, you could also do:

```
:g/[^\ ]ruby\ /
```

This would ensure there was a space before and after your ruby keyword.

Comment: but that wouldn't match `ruby` at the beginning or end of a line.